# Getting Bad Authentication data from twitter api | Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am using this url, can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?user_token=XXXX&user_secret=XXXX&consumer_key=XXXX&consumer_secret=XXXX&screen_name=twitterapi&count=5

Comment: (moved comment to answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not the correct way to pass the OAuth tokens to the API. You need to construct correct Authorization HTTP headers and sign your request. Something more like:

> GET
>   https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=twitterapi
>
> Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key=\"xxxxx\",
>   oauth_nonce=\"xxxx\", oauth_signature=\"xxxx\",
>   oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA1\", oauth_timestamp=\"xxxx\",
>   oauth_token=\"xxx\", oauth_version=\"1.0\"\r\n

Comment: Thanks Andy for your help.